# Logo not appearing on Metamask custom network

Tags: metamask

I know the title sounds similar to some other posted questions here, but hear me out.
I was exploring ways to add a custom token logo, ON a custom network.

Here's what I'm talking about :
[image]

Is there a way to add both custom network logo and custom token logo?
I'm aware it's possible for ERC-20 token from the guide here : https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/360059582151-How-to-add-a-token-logo

But the custom token logo has been added in both Ethereum and BSC network
[image]